# Python code not running input (Possibly menu related)

Tags: python, attributeerror

```
import circle
pi = 3.1415

def main():

        area(radius)
        circumference(radius)

def menu():
        
        print("Type a for area of circle")
        print("Type b for circumference of a circle")
        print("Type c to END PROGRAM")     
loop=True

while loop:
        menu()
        choice = input('Please enter your choice: ')

        if choice== "a":
                radius = float(input ("Input the radius of the circle : "))
                print(circle.area(radius))
        elif choice== "b":
                radius = float(input ("Input the radius of the circle : "))
                print(circle.circumference(radius))
        else:
                print("Goodbye!")
                

def area(radius):
    return pi * radius**2


def circumference(radius):
    return 2 * pi * radius

main()
```

In my last question, I recieved help on my menu (which is working now!) However, when I input the radius, I recieve the error:

**AttributeError: partially initialized module 'circle' has no attribute 'area' (most likely due to a circular import)**

Comment: Can you share the code of the module `circle`? Or is `circle` the file that's currently being executed? You can't import the same file you're running.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example]( https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made some changes to your code and it should work as intended. Let me know if you have any questions!

Basically, remove the import, remove the main() function, and shift the area() and circumference() to the top.

```
pi = 3.1415

# function to print the menu options
def menu():
    print("Type a for area of   ")
    print("Type b for circumference of a circle")
    print("Type c to END PROGRAM")

# function to calculate area
def area(radius):
    return pi * radius**2

# function to calculate circumference
def circumference(radius):
    return 2 * pi * radius

# menu loop
while True:

    # display menu
    menu()

    # prompt for user's choice
    choice = input('Please enter your choice: ')

    if choice == "a":
        radius = float(input("Input the radius of the circle : "))
        print(area(radius))
    elif choice == "b":
        radius = float(input("Input the radius of the circle : "))
        print(circumference(radius))
    else:
        print("Goodbye!")
        break
```

Comment: Thanks! I have been wrecking my head about this for an hour

Answer (score 0):

Kill `import circle` line. Change `circle.area` to `area` and `circle.circumference` to `circumference`. Move definitions of `area` and `circumference` functions to the top, so they are defined before they are used. Kill `main()` line in the end. Read https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html instead of typing magic spells you don't understand and hoping that they'll work somehow :)